# gallery and scrollview : a complete disaster!

Tags: android

ok so here I have a difficult one. apparently no1 does know a thing about this issue but I did find some app implementing the behaviour so hopefully...

I'll keep this short as I am sure if you stumbled upon it too, then you'll recognize the issue straight aways.

I have a horizontal Gallery with SrollViews in it. The 2 onTouchEvents (the one of the gallery and the one of the scrollview being displaied) collide and you need to take a decision about who to dispatch the event to.

anyone!?

please if u have no idea what I am talking about please let the http alone ... it's  already busy enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I have a horizontal Gallery with
>   SrollViews in it.

That is unlikely to work, for the reasons you discovered. Most likely, you will need to replace one or the other. For example, you could use a `ViewSwitcher` or `ViewFlipper` instead of a `Gallery`. I have also heard that `ScrollView` and `HoriztonalScrollView` actually work OK together, though I have not tried it.